# Can I recover data in Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-nodejs

I have a simple app, that stores some files in a node Heroku app.

I didn't know it, but every day the Heroku server is restarted and just the GitHub files survive. My ignored files not.

I know the date when I store those files in my app. Can I recover the Heroku App from that Day?.

Comment: Heroku does not offer any persistent file storage. You would need to send your files to something like S3. Examples and altternatives: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: It's highly unlikely Heroku can recover these files. Their docs are quite clear on this aspect of things. https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem